# Summarising occurrences and merging in R

Tags: r, count, group-by

Endeavouring to learn R, but seem to have hit a roadblock on something that is very simple to do in SQL.

Problem is as follows:
I have 2 tables:
Table A: consists of 'intial orders'. This is the first contact we have with a customer.
Table B: consists of 'secondary ordders', i.e. follow up orders related to the initial order.

There is a 1 to many relationship.
Table A has the following columns:

- Order number
- Order date
- part number
- customer ID

Table B has the following columns:

- order number
- order date
- part number
- initial order number

Assume each order is always a quantity of 1, but I can have multiple rows in B for each initial order in A.

What I want to do now is merge the two tables, but I want a summary, by B's part numbers, linked to A.

Data looks like this
A:

```
 Order_Num  Order_date  Part_Num  Cust_ID 
       100    1/1/2013      1001     1111 
       101   1/15/2013      1002     1111
```

B:

```
 Order_Num  Order_date  Part_Num  Init_Order_Num 
       200    2/1/2013      2001             100 
       201   3/15/2013      2002             100 
       202   4/18/2013      2002             100 
       203    5/1/2013      2002             101
```

What I'd like to see at the end is this:

```
 Order_Num  Order_date  Part_Num  Cust_ID  Count_Part_2001  Count_Part_2002 
       100    1/1/2013      1001     1111                1                2 
       101   1/15/2013      1002     1111                1
```

I've looked through various solutions here including using ddply, count, summarise, aggregate etc. but none seem to work. The data set has approximately 2.6m initial orders and 400k secondary orders.
Trying to use ddply, even when i reduce the data set to 1000 secondary orders still results in a out of memory error (i have 16GB in the machine).

in SQL i'd use a count(order number), group by part number on the secondary and then left join that with the initial order table on initial order number (would also do a pivot to create the 'Count_Part_2001' and 'Count_Part_2002' columns. Pivot works like the reverse of a melt() command in R).

Comment: It sounds very much like you're going to want to use **data.table**, which will solve your performance issues, and probably accomplish this in at most 2-3 lines. But we're going to need the example data in a more R friendly format.

Comment: @joran is right on efficiency, but if you're already familiar with sql, you can look at the `sqldf` package.

Comment: I believe the sample output is slightly incorrect. The last "1" should fall under "Count_Part_2002", correct?

Comment: oops, yes Ananda you are correct on that part

Answer (score 1):

It's easier if your variables are named in a more comparable way for merging. Here's an example of how you can proceed with `merge` and `aggregate` where I've just renamed your variables:

```
A <- structure(list(Ord_num_1 = c(100, 101), Ord_date_1 = c(" 1/1/2013   ", 
     " 1/15/2013  "), Part_num = c(1001, 1002), Cust_ID = c(1111,            
     1111)), .Names = c("Ord_num_1", "Ord_date_1", "Part_num", "Cust_ID"     
     ), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")  

B <- structure(list(Ord_num_2 = c(200, 201, 202, 203), Ord_date_2 = c(" 2/1/2013   ",   
     " 3/15/2013  ", " 4/18/2013  ", " 5/1/2013   "), Part_num = c(2001,                 
     2002, 2002, 2002), Ord_num_1 = c(100, 100, 100, 101)), .Names = c("Ord_num_2",      
     "Ord_date_2", "Part_num", "Ord_num_1"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

A and B now look like this:

```
A
#   Ord_num_1   Ord_date_1 Part_num Cust_ID
# 1       100  1/1/2013        1001    1111
# 2       101  1/15/2013       1002    1111
B
#   Ord_num_2   Ord_date_2 Part_num Ord_num_1
# 1       200  2/1/2013        2001       100
# 2       201  3/15/2013       2002       100
# 3       202  4/18/2013       2002       100
# 4       203  5/1/2013        2002       101
```

Let's merge them:

```
AB <- merge(A, B, by = "Ord_num_1")
#   Ord_num_1   Ord_date_1 Part_num.x Cust_ID Ord_num_2   Ord_date_2 Part_num.y
# 1       100  1/1/2013          1001    1111       200  2/1/2013          2001
# 2       100  1/1/2013          1001    1111       201  3/15/2013         2002
# 3       100  1/1/2013          1001    1111       202  4/18/2013         2002
# 4       101  1/15/2013         1002    1111       203  5/1/2013          2002
```

And `aggregate` them:

```
aggregate(Part_num.x ~ Ord_num_1 + Ord_date_1 + Cust_ID + Part_num.y, AB, length)
#   Ord_num_1   Ord_date_1 Cust_ID Part_num.y Part_num.x
# 1       100  1/1/2013       1111       2001          1
# 2       100  1/1/2013       1111       2002          2
# 3       101  1/15/2013      1111       2002          1
```

---

As @Joran mentioned, for large data, you should explore the `data.table` package. With that, the approach is very similar:

```
library(data.table)
DTA <- data.table(A, key = "Ord_num_1") ## Important for merging
DTB <- data.table(B, key = "Ord_num_1")
DTM <- merge(DTA, DTB)
DTM[, length(Part_num.x), by = c("Ord_num_1", "Ord_date_1", "Cust_ID", "Part_num.y")]
#    Ord_num_1   Ord_date_1 Cust_ID Part_num.y V1
# 1:       100  1/1/2013       1111       2001  1
# 2:       100  1/1/2013       1111       2002  2
# 3:       101  1/15/2013      1111       2002  1
```

---

As you can see, however, both of these solutions are in a "long" format. That said, I find that the long format is often easier to deal with.

Comment: @TheFlyingAfrican, I've expanded a bit on the explanation of what's going on [here](http://rpubs.com/mrdwab/reshaping-datatable). It also has a solution for going from long to wide, but I'm not sure how efficient it is.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a little bit of luck with `melt`, `dcast` and `reshape` functions. This is based on what you wanted for a final result and is not a complete table merge. Ananda was able to capture many of the other variables from table B. I'm not clear on reshape's ability to handle large data sets either, so the memory issue may still exist.

Starting from Ananda's example code:

```
B <- B[,3:4]
B$count <- 1
B
#Part_num Ord_num_1 count
#1     2001       100     1
#2     2002       100     1
#3     2002       100     1
#4     2002       101     1
mB <- melt(B, id=c("Ord_num_1", "Part_num"))
#mB
#Ord_num_1 Part_num variable value
#1       100     2001    count     1
#2       100     2002    count     1
#3       100     2002    count     1
#4       101     2002    count     1
cB <- dcast(mB, Ord_num_1 + Part_num ~ variable, sum)
cB
#  Ord_num_1 Part_num count
#1       100     2001     1
#2       100     2002     2
#3       101     2002     1
reshape(cB, timevar = "Part_num", idvar = "Ord_num_1", direction = "wide")
#Ord_num_1 count.2001 count.2002
#1       100          1          2
#3       101         NA          1
```

Which could then be merged to A using the `Ord_num_1` key. I'd be curious to see what you can come up with in the data.table package, which I have yet to try out.